# Filling hundreds SVG paths with an image causes serious performance issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, svg

I'm creating hexagonal tiles using SVG like that:

```
<style>
    .tile:hover {
        fill: red;
    }
</style>

<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    <g>
        <path
            d="M-17.32050807568877,-10L0,-20L17.32050807568877,-10L17.32050807568877,10.000000000000002L0,20.000000000000004L-17.32050807568877,10.000000000000002"
            class="tile"></path>

            ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have about 400 tiles on the screen. You can check how it looks here: https://337706.playcode.io/
Try to hover over some tiles. Hovered tiles should become red, and there is no performance issues.
There is also no issue if I fill all of the tiles with color:

```
<style>
    .tile {
        fill: green;
    }
</style>
```

I'd like to fill the tiles with an image, so I have created a pattern:

```
<defs>
    <pattern patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="grass" width="70" height="80">
        <image href="https://i.ibb.co/9ZZgDhy/tiles.png"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

And then, fill tiles with it:

```
<style>
    .tile {
        fill: url(#grass);
    }

    .tile:hover {
        fill: red;
    }
</style>
```

After that, the performance drops dramatically. (you can check it here, but bear in mind it may even crash your browser: https://337697.playcode.io/)

I have checked the profiler on Chrome, it says 98% of the time is spent on "Composite Layers".

[image]

I have noticed that the problem is not about the image itself but about the `<pattern>` because even if I remove the image and place just green rectangle instead, the performance is the same bad. If I remove the pattern and just fill the tile with color, there is no issue...

How can I fill the tiles with image and fix this performance issue? Is there a better way of setting the background image?

Comment: Are you filling the same image or a different image for each hexagon? Also it looks like the tiles are huge (1k x 1k px). Can you create them much smaller? Maybe also make use of `view box` for sizing? I'm wondering if the SVG itself could be optimized to reduce any performance issues before worrying about the pattern itself (though I do think that's an issue)

Comment: Here's a cool resource about [SVG performance](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch19-performance.html) Sounds like the `pattern` attribute is asking quite a lot of the composite process. Could you accomplish the same thing with CSS `clip-path`?

Comment: @BryceHowitson I'd like to have at most 10-20 different images. I'd like not to make them smaller. Can I use clip path to fill a path with an image?

Comment: I thought it may be due to the fact that the "honeycomb" is so inefficiently coded. So I've changed the code and I'm using `<use>` elements instead of so many paths. Still a problem.   This is a dumb question: can you consider to use the pattern on hover?

Comment: @enxaneta what do you mean "pattern on hover"?

Comment: Yes! The problem is using so many paths filled with a pattern. If I'm reducing the grid to 25 - 30 hexagons it's OK As soon as I increase the number of hexagons, the hovered hexagon is changing to red with a considerable delay. However if I have only one hexagon filled with a pattern - the one I mouse over - it works

Comment: @Mariusz.v7 Yes that's the entire purpose of `clip-path`. Basically, instead of an svg, you'll use an HTML element with a `background-image` clipped to the correct shape. I'll try to find some time to create an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the composite process with that many SVG's filled with a pattern is just asking too much. I'm basing that thought on this [write-up](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch19-performance.html). I'm not sure if there is a good way to improve that, but there are other ways to accomplish what you want.

---

#### Here's an example using `css clip-path` in place of an SVG.

Note you need to do a bit more work in CSS to correctly position everything.

Each hexagon is a square and all corners land on a quarter or half. That makes the math a bit easier. I'm absolutely positioning each tile and then providing `height`, `width`, X (`left:offset`) and Y (`top:offset`) via the Javascript when they're appended.

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/KjPOgP) if you want to play with it.

It **seems quite performant** even with 2500 elements...

```js
var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var totalCols = 10;
var totalRows = 15;
var stepX = (1/totalCols) * 100;
var stepY = stepX * 0.75;

for (let r=0; r<totalRows; r++ ){
 for(let c=0; c<totalCols; c++){
  var offset = (r % 2) ? (stepX * 0.5) : 0;
  addHexagon(offset + c * stepX, r * stepY);
 }
}

function addHexagon (x,y) {
 var newPos = 
  'top: ' + y + '%;' +
  'left: ' + x + '%;' +
  'width: ' + stepX +'%;' +
  'height: ' + stepX + '%;'
 var el = document.createElement('div')
 el.setAttribute('class', 'el')
 el.setAttribute('style', newPos);
 container.appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
 width:1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 background: #333;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.el {
 position: absolute;
 /* set height & width using js */
    /* make the hexagon and mask the content */
 clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
 
 /* asethetic only */
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560146491-308b0f69a52a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=80);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.el:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be quicker using clipped images.

I've created the map using a nested loop to create a bunch of `<use>` elements.  The downside to this method is that you can't do a simple CSS colour change on hover.

```js
var map = document.getElementById("map");

var SVG_NS = map.namespaceURI;
var XLINK_NS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

var H_STEP = 34.64;
var V_STEP = 30;

var y = 0;

for (let j=0; j<20; j++) {
  var xStart = (j % 2) ? (H_STEP / 2) : 0;
  for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
    addUse("grass", xStart + i * H_STEP, j * V_STEP);
  }
}


function addUse(defId, x, y) {
  var use = document.createElementNS(map.namespaceURI, "use");
  use.setAttributeNS(XLINK_NS, "xlink:href", "#"+defId);
  use.setAttribute("x", x);
  use.setAttribute("y", y);
  map.appendChild(use);
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="hexagon">
      <path d="M0,10 L17.32,0 L34.64,10 L34.64,30 L17.32,40 L0,30 Z"/>
    </clipPath>

    <image id="grass" href="https://i.ibb.co/9ZZgDhy/tiles.png"
           width="105" height="80" clip-path="url(#hexagon)"/>
  </defs>

  <g id="map">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: seems good, but why we can't use css hover? does js events like "onclick" work for each tile? later I'll experiment with your code but it's promising.

Comment: A `<use>` is a fixed reference to the image in the `<defs>` section.  All references to `<image id="grass"...>` will be identical.  You can style the `<use>` element itself. But there are very few style changes you can make to a `<use>`.  Instead you'll likely have to use JS `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to change the `href` attribute instead.

Comment: Yes. You can add click events to the `<use>` element.